# When developing an xml layout using Coordinator Layout, Accessibility focus order has been changed not as like in creating other layout or viewgroups

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I´m facing an accessibility focus order issue in Coordinator Layout with the Drawer Layout in Android.

Example:
In CollapsingToolbarLayout widget i have added profile icon and other items.

When CollapsingToolbarLayout widget is in expand mode, the initial Accessibility focus highlight presented in profile icon or the widget which present inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout.

But The Expected initial accessibility focus order should be in the Drawer icon as per the  Android Accessibility standards.

I have tested in Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow) and i believe it is happening in all android versions which has implemented using material design.

Tested in Samsung Galaxy S7 Device

Hereby, I have added youtube video link for your referece or more clarity on this issue

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLRKTIo9Su8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_PJ7plkXKY&spfreload=10

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue. Using the AccessibilityManager to send an accessibility event doesn't seem to be working.